# How to keep a very large dictionary loaded in memory in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory, large-data

I have a very large dictionary of size ~ 200 GB which I need to query very often for my algorithm. To get quick results, I want to put it in memory which is possible, because fortunately I have a 500GB RAM.

However, my main issue is that I want to load it only once in memory and then let other processes query the same dictionary, rather than having to load it again everytime I create a new process or iterate over my code.

So, I would like something like this:

Script 1:

```
 # Load dictionary in memory
 def load(data_dir):
     dictionary = load_from_dir(data_dir) ...
```

Script 2:

```
 # Connect to loaded dictionary (already put in memory by script 1)
 def use_dictionary(my_query):
     query_loaded_dictionary(my_query)
```

What's the best way to achieve this ? I have considered a rest API, but I wonder if going over a REST request will erode all the speed I gained by putting the dictionary in memory in the first place.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: maybe use something like redis would be help.

Comment: yes, redis is also a good idea. I was wondering if there is a way to do this in python. I earlier tried mongodb, but the latest wiredtiger version of mongodb, doesn't have an option to pre-load all the data in memory.  The problem is that I don't have root password, so I didn't want to install too many software. But let me try redis.

Comment: Are you trying to re-invent the NOSQL databases? Why not rely on existing ones?

Comment: Another possibility is to use a `shelve`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html

Comment: It's mainly because I already wrote a thread-safe code to quickly load and serve data from memory which was significantly faster than mongodb. I just wanted to find out if there was a strictly "python" way to re-use what I did without having to rewrite code for porting to a new database.

Comment: I saw another problem with redis, it doesn't support nested hashes. My structure is 3-level nested.

Comment: Then a separate MongoDB server is probably more appropriate. Or serialize the nested dicts into Redis and deserialize on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Either run a separate service that you access with a REST API like you mentioned, or use an in-memory database.

I had a very good experience with [Redis](http://redis.io/) personally, but there are many others ([Memcached](https://memcached.org/) is also popular). Redis was easy to use with Python and Django.

In both solutions there can be data serialization though, so some performance will be dropped. There is a way to fill Redis with simple structures such as lists, but I haven't tried. I packed my numeric arrays and serialized them (with numpy), it was fast enough in the end. If you use simple string key-value pairs anyway, then the performance will be optimal, and maybe better with memcached.